# Azure Notification Hub 400 on Registration for Push

Tags: cordova, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I am currently having issues with Azure Notifications - I have configured everything for production, and confirmed this worked by sending a test notification. However, after the first 'registerForPushNotifications' in the app, the next time I open it I get the following error logged:

`PID[11096] Information Sending response: 400.0 <Error><Code>400</Code><Detail>Installation validation failed with following error(s):&#xD;
An invalid tag(s) '_UserId:facebook|10211219930003961,NewVenue' was supplied. Valid tag characters are alphanumeric, _, @, -, ., : and #..TrackingId:9315e728-8777-4cad-a475-956c38dcde36_G6,TimeStamp:4/23/2017 9:09:06 AM</Detail></Error>`

I am registering for push from a cordova (ionic) application using the boilerplate code provided. I cannot understand where I am going wrong. I want to fix this as it is an issue in production at the moment.

Subscription Code:

```
function registerForPushNotifications() {
      pushRegistration = PushNotification.init({
        android: {
          senderID: '<id>'
        },
        ios: {
          alert: 'true',
          badge: 'true',
          sound: 'true'
        },
        wns: {}
      });

      // Handle the registration event.
      pushRegistration.on('registration', function(data) {
        // Get the native platform of the device.
        if (device) {
          debugger
          var platform = device.platform;
          // Get the handle returned during registration.
          var handle = data.registrationId;
          // Set the device-specific message template.
          if (platform == 'android' || platform == 'Android') {
            // Register for GCM notifications.
            window.azureClient.push.register('gcm', handle.replace("|",""), {
              mytemplate: {
                body: {
                  data: {
                    message: "{$(messageParam)}"
                  }
                }
              }
            });
          } else if (device.platform === 'iOS') {
            // Register for notifications.
            window.azureClient.push.register('apns', handle.replace("|",""), {
              mytemplate: {
                body: {
                  aps: {
                    alert: "{$(messageParam)}"
                  }
                }
              }
            });
          } else if (device.platform === 'windows') {
            // Register for WNS notifications.
            window.azureClient.push.register('wns', handle.replace("|",""), {
              myTemplate: {
                body: '<toast><visual><binding template="ToastText01"><text id="1">$(messageParam)</text></binding></visual></toast>',
                headers: {
                  'X-WNS-Type': 'wns/toast'
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });

      pushRegistration.on('notification', function(data, d2) {
        alert('Push Received: ' + data.message);
      });

      pushRegistration.on('error', function(err) {
        console.warn("error", err)
      });
    }
```

Comment: Would be good to tell us how you are registering?  Is it via the Azure App Service or direct to the Notification Hub?  What does your Installation object look like?  You've obviously altered the boiler-plate since you have added 'NewVenue' which isn't standard in the boiler-plate.

Comment: I have enabled push in the blade under the azure mobile app. I register from the app using the code i added in the edit. I don't know where 'newVenue' comes from - i did create that as a tag in the push blade, with 'automatically added' selected.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Mobile Apps SDK for Apache Cordova does not work with installations yet.  You need to do a HTTP POST request to the `/push/installations/{applicationId}` endpoint (which is the endpoint that the push blade configures for you).  The body must be a valid Installation object for a Notification Hub.

I talk through the process for this using C# as the language in my book (http://aka.ms/zumobook).  This will allow you to fine-tune the push parameters you send since you are sending the configuration object that is directly related to the push object.

Comment: Great, thanks will give this a shot. Did something change though as I swear this exact thing worked previously in one of my other apps? Or am i going crazy?

Comment: Also, where do I obtain the {applicationId} value?

Comment: After an analysis of the code, I've found a bug with facebook auth and Azure App Service Push blade.  I'm working on getting a fix out to you.  Can you please contact me at zumopm@microsoft.com and we'll get some more information sorted.  The applicationID is available in the SDK at client.getApplicationInstallationId()